# How to calculate the corresponding matrix to combine with in order to achieve a specific target Euler rotation in XYZ?

Tags: java, math, matrix, skeletal-mesh, joml

I am given a rotation matrix `constant` that is immutable and should not be modified with rotations of `30`, `20`, and `10` degrees about XYZ.

I need to create a matrix `attempt` that, when either pre or post multiplied with `constant` will create a matrix with rotations of `90`, `-20`, and `-10` degrees about XYZ and equal to `target`.

```java
Matrix4d target = new Matrix4d()
    .rotationXYZ(Math.toRadians(30 + 60), Math.toRadians(20 - 40), Math.toRadians(10 - 20)); // 90, -20, -10

System.out.println(new Vector3d(8.0).mulProject(target)); // Target * V = (5.973 -10.687 6.489)

Matrix4d constant = new Matrix4d()
    .rotationXYZ(Math.toRadians(30), Math.toRadians(20), Math.toRadians(10)); // A

Matrix4d attempt = new Matrix4d()
    .rotationXYZ(Math.toRadians(60), Math.toRadians(-40), Math.toRadians(-20)); // B

Matrix4d combined = constant.mulLocal(attempt, new Matrix4d()); // C = B * A
System.out.println(new Vector3d(8.0).mulProject(combined)); // Combined * V = (1.84 -10.747 8.55)
```

As shown above, the `attempt` matrix rotates by the extra amount required in each axis after the `constant`. This resulting `combined` matrix does not equal the `target` though.

```java
Matrix4d attempt = new Matrix4d()
    .rotationXYZ(Math.toRadians(90), Math.toRadians(-20), Math.toRadians(-10))
    .mul(constant.invert(new Matrix4d()));
```

This second attempt works, but it requires that I inverse the work of `constant` first which is a waste of resources. I would like to find the correct rotation values to give to `rotationXYZ` or `rotate` with a quaternion without inversing the previous matrix.

Comment: You clarified what you are doing and what you want to do. However, chat is the exact question/problem?

Comment: This is really just a [math.se] question: You have an input matrix, let's call it **A**, you know what result you should get, let's call it **B**, and now you want to know what **M** solves **AM=B** or **MA=B**. And that's "how do I solve a matrix equation", not a programming question. (lots of good pages and videos that teach you how to do this that you can then try to implement yourself).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I wanted an answer in the context of JOML that was more efficient than inverting a single matrix and applying a new total rotation. I now understand that it is 3 separate rotations combined in order and the ZYX functions allow me to do the inverse in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we must know precisely what rotateXYZ does. From
https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Matrix4f.html#rotateXYZ(float,float,float,org.joml.Matrix4f)

> Apply rotation of angleX radians about the X axis, followed by a rotation of angleY radians about the Y axis and followed by a rotation of angleZ radians about the Z axis.

So we can think of this as apply rotations Rx, Ry, Rz to our starting matrix M to give resulting matrix M'.

```
M' = Rz Ry Rx M
```

Now a very important point about matrix multiplication is that order of applying matrices is important, i.e. it is not commutative. So using a different order say

```
M'' = Rx Ry Rz M
```

will in general be different to M'.

Here we have two matrices

```
target = Rz(-10) * Ry(-20) * Rx(90)
constant = Rz(10) * Ry(20) * Rx(10)
```

and wish to find matrix `attempt` such that

```
target = attempt * constant
```

Or

target = attempt * Rz(10) * Ry(20) * Rx(10)

Now we can apply the inverse of the compentent rotations. Note that the inverse of a rotation matrix Rx(theta) is the rotation matrix Rx(-theta), (a clockwise rotation is the inverse of an anti-clockwise rotation).

So we apply the rotations applying the inverses on the right

```
target = attempt * Rz(10) * Ry(20) * Rx(10) 
target * Rx(-10) = attempt * Rz(10) * Ry(20)  
target * Rx(-10) * Ry(-20) = attempt * Rz(10)
target * Rx(-10) * Ry(-20) * Rz(-10) = attempt
```

Note the difference in order the last matrices are applied in the order Z, Y, X.

Now JOML has method for matrices in every possible order and the method we want is

> public Matrix4f rotateZYX(Vector3f angles)

> Apply rotation of angles.z radians about the Z axis, followed by a rotation of angles.y radians about the Y axis and followed by a rotation of angles.x radians about the X axis.

So to find attempt we can take

```
inverse = new Matrix4d()
.rotationZYX(Math.toRadians(-10), Math.toRadians(-20), Math.toRadians(-10))
attempt = target.clone()
attempt.mul(inverse) // i.e. attempt = target * inverse
```

Or more simply

```
attempt = target.clone()
attempt.rotationZYX(Math.toRadians(-10), Math.toRadians(-20), Math.toRadians(-10))
```